How to convert nuget-tree to JSON format
I've a requirement to load list of packages used in my C# project. So, I used npm-tree. It is returning list in tree format. But I want in JSON Format.
Tree Format
├── Antlr 3.5.0.2
├── Castle.Core 4.4.0
├── Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.7
├─┬ Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.LocalDB 2.0.1
│ └── Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core 2.0.0
├── Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.7
├── Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization 1.1.3
├─┬ Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.7
│ └── Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.7  

JSON Format
{
    "Antlr 3.5.0.2": [],
    "Castle.Core 4.4.0": [],
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.7": [],
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.LocalDB": [
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core 2.0.0"],
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.7": [],
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.7": [
        "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.7"]
}

Any help could be appreciated. Thanks in advance

What "tree format" are you talking about? And what are you actually looking for? What you posted is how a tool displays package dependency information, not how that information is actually stored. npm stores the actual data in package.json. NuGet or rather asset dependency information is already stored in obj/projects.assets.json.

If you really want to convert that, take System.Text.Json or Newtonsoft.Json. E.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/overview
